# SqlTableProfileProvider, custom ProfileBase class, add extra attributes to properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using SqlTableProfileProvider as my profile provider and a custom class called 'ProfileCommon' inheriting from System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase. My ProfileCommon class properties that represent the columns in my profile table each get an attribute of [CustomProviderData("columnName;dbType")]. I am trying to add a new attribute to specific column and then am going to pull that info from the SqlTableProfileProvider class.

The team and I are looking to associate a foreign key (table) with our Profile table. Right now, our Profile table stores, basically, key value pairs, FirstName, LastName, Age, etc; however, we are planning to store bookmarks, links to favorite articles and what not, that will be presented in a list on our dashboard page. We like using the SqlTableProfileProvider and the ProfileCommon object I created. All our asp.net pages inherit from a BasePage and a property called Profile gets the profile common object.

It would be nice to just be able to do:

```
Profile.Bookmarks.Count; // to know if there are bookmarks

// to also just be able to foreach through them
foreach (Bookmark bk in Profile.Bookmarks) { ... }
```

Ex:

```
public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase
{
    public static ProfileCommon GetProfile() { .... }

    [CustomProviderData("FirstName;varchar")]
    public virtual string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("FirstName")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", value);
        }
    }

    [CustomProviderData("LastName;varchar")]
    public virtual string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("LastName")));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("LastName", value);
        }
    }

    [CustomProviderData("OtherColumn;int")]
    [TableNameData("OtherTable")]
    public virtual int OtherColumn
    {
        get ...
        set ...
    }
}

// My new attribute
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TableNameData : Attribute
{
    private string _tableName;

    public TableNameData(string tableName)
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    public string TableName
    {
        get
        {
            return _tableName;
        }
    }
}

// Not my implementation, but looking to enhance it.
public class SqlTableProfileProvider : ProfileProvider
{
    public override SettingsPropertyValueCollection GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection svc, string username, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        ...
        foreach (SettingsProperty prop in properties)
        {
            ...
            // in here, gets CustomProviderData
            string persistenceData = prop.Attributes["CustomProviderData"] as string.

            // how do i get to mine?
        }
    }
}
```

The SqlTableProfileProvider was implemented by Hao Kung. It inherits from ProfileProvider.

One of the methods GetPropertyValues returns a SettingsPropertyValueCollection. There is a private method called GetProfileDataFromTable. In there, I wish to access my custom attribute that I created.

Question: How do I access my attribute that I have specified on my property?

UPDATE: 07162011:1517, 7 days after question asked,

I did find a way to do this. The following is how I did it:

```
// In the default constructor add the following
public ProfileCommon()
{
    //  Get all properties for this class 'ProfileCommon'
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(ProfileCommon).GetProperties();

    //  The ProfileBase, base class, has a property called Properties and 
    //  one can get to all attributes on that property but there are only
    //  a few attributes that ProfileBase looks for. If the developer wishes
    //  to use custom attributes on a property, it wont appear in the 
    //  ProfileCommon.Properties.Attributes list.
    //  
    //  So, what are we going to do, well, we are going to come up with a hack and solution to this problem
    //
    foreach (SettingsProperty settingsProperty in ProfileCommon.Properties)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            if (settingsProperty.Name == propertyInfo.Name)
            {
                //  get all attributes from the associated property, but we are getting it from the propertyInfo variable
                //  which was retrieved through reflection and will list ALL attributes.
                    object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

                for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Type type = attributes[i].GetType();

                    PropertyInfo[] attributeClassProperities = type.GetProperties();

                    foreach (PropertyInfo attributeClassProperty in attributeClassProperities)
                    {
                        //  not intested in the TypeId property for the object
                        if (!attributeClassProperty.Name.Equals("TypeId"))
                        {
                            //  if the settingsProperty.Attributes does not contain our key value pair, then add it.
                            if (settingsProperty.Attributes[attributeClassProperty.Name] == null)
                            {
                                    settingsProperty.Attributes.Add(attributeClassProperty.Name, attributes[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to take care of implementing your ProfileCommon as you have in the example and make sure the attributes are correct.

For the specialized profile property Bookmark you would also write your own profile class just as you have in the example. There you have to implement a Count property that would query the database for the number of bookmarks of that user.

In the Profile table in the database you would have a Bookmarks column with a suitable FK type such as Guid, Int or BigInt that would be nothing more than a Foreign key to another table you could name [dbo].[Bookmarks] that would actually contain the bookmarks for each user. This Bookmarks table should have a column like UserId that would be a FK to the ASP.NET UserId.